# manual input for (ddd mm.m) convert to radians or decimal degrees? In python

Tags: python, if-statement, navigation, latitude-longitude, astronomy

I am writing a Python program for astronomical navigation using sextant observations as manual input. I use an angular form (ddd mm.m) or degrees, minutes and decimal minutes. I'm using the math library for further computations in my code. What would you suggest I do when the Lat/Lon are implemented in the program convert, them to radians or would decimal degrees be fine?.

My test position DR: 27°40.0'N; 102°22.5'W

```
    # DR: Dead Reckoning
latDR1 = input(float('div latidude degrees as (dd)')) #27
latDR2 = input(float('div latitude minutes as (mm.m)'))#40.0
latDR3 = input('div latitude hemisphere N/S')#N
latDR = float(latDR1+(latDR2/60))
if latDR3 == S: -(latDR);
    else: # here the error shows: 
else:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent       

latDR

lonDR1 = input(float('div longditude degrees as (ddd)'))#102
lonDR2 = input(float('div longditude minutes as (mm.m)'))#22.5
lonDR3 = input('div longditude hemisphere E/W')#W
lonDR = float(latDR1+(latDR2/60))
if latDR3 == W: -(latDR);
    else: 
        latDR

DR = (latDR, lonDR)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are wanting to do with the values of latitude and longitude later. Normally they are needed for trigonometric functions (`sin`, `cos`, `tan` etc) which will need the arguments to be in radians. This is easy to do with `math.radians()` and the result after calculation can be converted back for display with `math.degrees()`.

A word of advice: when reading sexagesimal values in parts as you are, you will want to combine the degrees, minutes and seconds (or decimal minutes) to decimal degrees first, *then* apply negation or a `-1` multiplier for your sign convention (North & East +ve in your case; other choices are available for longitude...) if applicable. For example if you had 27deg 45.0' S, you want `-1 * (27.0 + (45.0/60.0)) = -27.75` not `-27.0 + (45.0/60.0) = -26.25`